# Embedding video with object tag for self hosted content and player

Tags: html, video, video-player, brightcove, object-tag

I am new to video player world. I want to develop a mobile browser based video player. I know HTML5 and its flash fall back but this is a different requirement .

The requirement is, using Object tag I should embed my video so that it Plays in all the mobile devices(Browser). Code help will be highly useful . It mandatory to use Object tag . If any swf or anything like that which is compatible to all mobile browsers..

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<object>`-tag is a bad way. Why is it mandatory for your use? Why not go with the `<video>`-tag instead? Also, `<object>` is deprecated as of January 27, 2015.

If the file you want to embed is playable by most phones (such as a .MP4 file), you can use the `<video>`-tag instead.

```
<video width="500" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

If you're embedding an .swf file, you cannot play it on devices with no flash support. I am unable to play .swf files natively in Chrome on my Android phone, and don't even think about iOS devices.

If you really, **REALLY** want to use the `<object>`-tag as well, you can wrap that inside a `<video>`-tag, like this:

```
<video src="video.mp4" controls>
    <object data="flvplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param value="flvplayer.swf" name="movie"/>
    </object>
</video>
```